# Plots are not drawn and ACTION_MOVE not detected in OnTouchListener

Tags: android, ontouchlistener, androidplot

I am trying to create different charts for my App and I use AndroidPlot. I want to swipe between different plots, so that when I swipe left a new chart is drawn for example.

I have implemented `OnTouchListener` and a function `drawChart(String Discipline)` that shall draw the chart, however, when drawChart is called from `OnTouch`, it does not work.

Moreover, if I try to detect an ACTION_MOVE, nothing happens, only ACTION_DOWN is detected. I do not see why.

Here is the code:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


import com.androidplot.Plot;
import com.androidplot.xy.BoundaryMode;
import com.androidplot.xy.LineAndPointFormatter;
import com.androidplot.xy.PointLabelFormatter;
import com.androidplot.xy.SimpleXYSeries;
import com.androidplot.xy.XYPlot;
import com.androidplot.xy.XYSeries;
import com.androidplot.xy.XYStepMode;

import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public class DrawChartsFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnTouchListener{
    XYPlot plot;

    public DrawChartsFragment() {
    }

    Number[] getXcoord(int length){
        Number[] tmp = new Number[length];
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++){
            tmp[i] = i;
        }
        return tmp;
    }

    private void drawChart(String Discipline){
        plot = (XYPlot)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.plot);

        Number[] data = Statistic.getDataPoint(Discipline);
        List<Number> list = Arrays.asList(data);
        Number[] x = getXcoord(list.size());
        XYSeries series = new SimpleXYSeries(Arrays.asList(x),list,Discipline);
        LineAndPointFormatter series1Format = new LineAndPointFormatter();
        series1Format.setPointLabelFormatter(new PointLabelFormatter());
        series1Format.configure(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                R.xml.line_point_formatter_with_labels);
        plot.setDomainStep(XYStepMode.INCREMENT_BY_VAL, 5);
        plot.setRangeBoundaries(0, 100, BoundaryMode.FIXED);
        plot.setRangeStep(XYStepMode.INCREMENT_BY_VAL, 10);
        plot.addSeries(series, series1Format);
        plot.setTitle(Discipline);
    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        plot = (XYPlot)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.plot);
        // plot.setOnTouchListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_draw_charts, container, false);
        rootView.setOnTouchListener(this);
        return rootView;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        drawChart("Skeet");
        switch (event.getAction()){
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            MainActivity.showToast("Move");
            return true;
    }
    return false;
        return false;
    }
}
```

If I call `drawChart("Skeet")` from `onActivityCreated`, it works fine. But when called from `OnTouchListener`, then I only get a lot of messages like:

> Looking up object containing: textPaint.color
>
> Attempting to find getter for textPaint in class com.androidplot.xy.PointLabelFormatter
>
> Invoking getTextPaint on instance of
> com.androidplot.xy.PointLabelFormatter

It seems like it cannot read the parameters from the xml-file? Any ideas are appreciated!

/ Erik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the following to the end of **drawChart()** should get things working:

```
plot.redraw();
```

You need to call **Plot.redraw()** when making changes to series data, add or remove series in a plot or alter display params such as line color, thickness etc. outside of **onActivityCreated()**.  The reason it works when called from **onActivityCreated()** is because that code runs before Androidplot finishes initialization.  Once initialization has completed, **redraw()** is automatically invoked one time to ensure that the plot is always visible.